# I have to store multiple images in a string variable so that i can hand that variable over to table object to save it into single database column

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string fileName = "";
    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in imgupld.PostedFiles)
    {
      fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
      postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ADMINDASHBOARD/EVENT/" + fileName));
      ev.PHOTOS = fileName; 
    } 
    ev.TITLE = txttitle.Text.Trim();
    ev.YER = Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue);
    objlayer.saveevents(ev);
 }
```

I have this code to save multiple images to a folder named Event and then database. All the images are getting saved to folder but only one image is getting saved into database column named PHOTOS. I want to save all the images into a single column cell of column PHOTOS in one go. Datatype of column PHOTOS is varchar(max).

Edit:

```
public void saveevents(CONNECTION.EVNT ev)
{
    ev.CRDT = DateTime.Now;
    ev.ISACT = 0;
    con.da.EVNTs.InsertOnSubmit(ev);
    con.da.SubmitChanges(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the savevents call is outside the foreach (I'm assuming that saveevents is where you are saving to database). Try this:

```
    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in imgupld.PostedFiles)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ADMINDASHBOARD/EVENT/" + fileName));
        ev.PHOTOS = fileName; 
        ev.TITLE = txttitle.Text.Trim();
        ev.YER = Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue);
        objlayer.saveevents(ev);
    }
```

Be aware that ev object is not initialized. It's a better solution to create a new object in each loop. In my case, I use to add an Id property in my entities. If Id == 0 then is a new entity, If Id != 0 then the Save method treat it as an update.

**Changes after comments:**

```
    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in imgupld.PostedFiles)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ADMINDASHBOARD/EVENT/" + fileName));
        CONNECTION.EVNT ev = new CONNECTION.EVNT();  //this line is new
        ev.PHOTOS = fileName; 
        ev.TITLE = txttitle.Text.Trim();
        ev.YER = Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue);
        objlayer.saveevents(ev);
    }
```

Comment: public void saveevents(CONNECTION.EVNT ev)
       {
           ev.CRDT = DateTime.Now;
           ev.ISACT = 0;
           con.da.EVNTs.InsertOnSubmit(ev);
           con.da.SubmitChanges();
           
       }

Comment: The only thing I can recomend you is to debug the InsertOnSubmit method and see whats happen. Also, try the changes I made in my response